# Cannot send post data via chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I have an API endpoint that exists, and I know it works correctly (I test frequently, successfully using PostMan). The problem is that when I am posting to it via my chrome extension, I am able to connect, however, no data values are being sent.

Here's my chrome manifest:
{

> ```
> "background": {
>     "scripts": ["eventPage.js","jquery-3.3.1.min.js"],
>     "persistent": false
> },
>
> "content_scripts": [
>     {
>         "matches": ["https://*.amazon.com/*"],
>         "js": ["content.js", "jquery-3.3.1.min.js", "inject.js"],
>         "css": ["content.css"]
>     }
> ],
>
> "permissions": [
>     "tabs",
>     "storage",
>     "https://*.amazon.com/*",
>     "https://*.cloudfunctions.net/*"
> ] }
> ```

Here is the event page that makes the call:

```
// listen to all messages at runtime
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if (request.todo == 'sendLoad') {
        console.log("MADE IT! Request Data", request.data)
        // FYI the request.data output is correct; everything is there

        // AJAX
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://prefix.cloudfunctions.net/endpoint",
            type: "post",
            data: {productName: encodeURIComponent(jQuery.trim(request.data.productName)), productImg: encodeURIComponent(request.data.productImg), productUrl: encodeURIComponent(request.data.productUrl), price: request.data.price, byLineValue: request.data.byLineValue, byLineUrl: encodeURIComponent(request.data.byLineUrl), amazonPath: encodeURIComponent(request.data.amazonPath[2]), uid: request.data.uid, tid: "1"} ,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("Send complete: ", response);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }  
        });

    };
});
```

(FYI, I also just tried to send `request.data` alone and was unsuccessful.)
I also tried to make the call using an xmlhttp request:

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST","https://prefix.cloudfunctions.net/endpoint",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(request.data);
```

And I also tried using a jQuery post:

```
$.post("https://prefix.cloudfunctions.net/endpoint",{{productName: encodeURIComponent(jQuery.trim(request.data.productName)), productImg: encodeURIComponent(request.data.productImg), productUrl: encodeURIComponent(request.data.productUrl), price: request.data.price, byLineValue: request.data.byLineValue, byLineUrl: encodeURIComponent(request.data.byLineUrl), amazonPath: encodeURIComponent(request.data.amazonPath[2]), uid: request.data.uid, tid: "1"})
.done(function (data) {
    console.log("Send complete: " + data);
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("Error sending data")
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("jQuery Post complete")
})
```

For each of these my API is returning a message that the values do not exist:

```
Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value (found in field productImg).
    at Object.validateUserInput (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/serializer.js:273:15)
    at Object.validateDocumentData (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:622:26)
    at CollectionReference.add (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:1743:23)
    at exports.addToTrunk.functions.https.onRequest (/srv/lib/index.js:27:14)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
    at /worker/worker.js:783:7
    at /worker/worker.js:766:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

As I mentioned earlier, the endpoint works successfully but is not finding the data values that are sent.

**UPDATE:**
It's looking like the firebase "add" function that's not working correctly. Here is the code in the firebase function:

```
  newTrunk.add({
    created_at: created_at,
    uid: "CG8B0mdqzMed3PPCiwsKkBtXmiA2", //request.body.uid, //TODO: pull in uid from localstorage
    tid: '1', //TODO: provide list of trunks for person to select from when adding via extension
    productImg: JSON.stringify(request.body.productImg),
        price: JSON.stringify(request.body.price),
    productUrl: JSON.stringify(request.body.productUrl),
    byLineValue: JSON.stringify(request.body.byLineValue),
    byLineUrl: JSON.stringify(request.body.byLineUrl),
    amazonPath: JSON.stringify(request.body.amazonPath),
    source: JSON.stringify(request.body.source),
    productName: JSON.stringify(request.body.productName)
    // Tried to stringify and see if it would help ... it didn't
    // productImg: request.body.productImg,
        // price: request.body.price,
    // productUrl: request.body.productUrl,
    // byLineValue: request.body.byLineValue,
    // byLineUrl: request.body.byLineUrl,
    // amazonPath: request.body.amazonPath,
    // source: request.body.source,
    // productName: request.body.productName
  })
  .then(function(docRef) {
        // console.log("TCL: docRef", docRef)
    console.log("New item in trunk added with ID: ", docRef.id)
    response.status(200).send("Successful")
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error adding newTrunk: ", error)
    response.status(500).send(error)
  });
```

Comment: Compare all headers and body of the request using devtools Network panel (not console) for the event page to those in Postman and find the difference.

Comment: looks like cors  or corb issue, what is showing in network panel ?

Comment: Actually, have no errors in the Network panel. And in fact, I can actually output the values in the Firebase Functions console. It's looking more specifically like the 
 Firestore DB cannot run the "add". I'm going to update the question details above to reflect this.